# Change button after submit - jquery, django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

i have an ajax "follow" button. It works fine and after submit the button's attribute `disabled` becomes `"disabled"`. But i want to change "follow" button to "unfollow" button after submit just like in Twitter. How to do this? I Tried this to change button's attribute "form" to submit another form:

```
success:function(){
                $button.attr('form','unfollow');
```

but unfortunately it doesnt work.

template **event.html:**

```
   {% if user in event.users.all %}
            <form id="unfollow">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="remove">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{% trans "Unfollow"%}</button>
            </form>
    {% else %}
            <form id="follow">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="add">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{% trans "Follow"%}</button>
            </form>
    {% endif %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('submit','#unfollow', function(e){
        var $button = $(this).find('button');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/event/{{ event.id }}/',
            data: "remove={{ event.id }}",
            success:function(){
                $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('{% trans "Unfollowed" %}');
            }
        })
    });

    $(document).on('submit','#follow', function(e){
        var $button = $(this).find('button');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/event/{{ event.id }}/',
            data: "add={{ event.id }}",
            success:function(){
                 $button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('{% trans "Followed" %}');
            }
        })
    });

</script>
```

**views.py**

```
user = request.user
if request.GET.get('add'):
    event.users.add(user)
    event.save()
if request.GET.get('remove'):
    event.users.remove(user)
    event.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add both forms, always, and hide/show appropriately like this:

```
<form id="unfollow" {% if user not in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="remove">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{% trans "Unfollow"%}</button>
</form>

<form id="follow"% if user in event.users.all %}style="display:none;"{% endif %}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="add">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{% trans "Follow"%}</button>
</form>
```

Change your JS to:

```
success: function() {  // in your follow form
    $followForm.hide();
    $unfollowForm.show();
}

success: function() {  // in your unfollow form
    $unfollowForm.hide();
    $followForm.show();
}
```

You could also use some state variable to decide which form to hide and which to show.

SIDE NOTE:
You should prefer POST instead of GET for submits that change the state.

Answer (score 5):

One major issue here is that you have two endpoints (follow / unfollow) for a quite similar treatment.

First, to simplify everything, you could have a single endpoint that will just **switch the status** (from follow to unfollow, and vice versa). Thanks to this, you will only send the event ID using a **single form**.

I am not a python guy at all, but everything should look like this:

**views.py**

```
user = request.user
if request.GET.get('eventId'):
    # if the user is in event.users, then remove it, otherwise, add it (sorry I don't know the Python syntax here, but it is quite a simple condition).
    # The algorithm would be like this:
    # isFollowing = user in event.users
    # if (isFollowing) then event.users.remove(user)
    #     else event.users.add(user)
    event.save()
    # Next, return JSON (see how to do it with Django):
    # return {"following": !isFollowing}
```

**template.html**

```
<form class="formFollowEvent"> <!-- Based on a class and not an ID, in case you want to have multiple follow / unfollow buttons on a same page, even for different events -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ event.id }}" name="eventId">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">
        {% if user in event.users.all %}
            {% trans "Unfollow" %}
        {% else %}
            {% trans "Follow" %}
        {% endif %} <!-- There should be something better with your template engine to handle the follow / unfollow translation -->
    </button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('.formFollowEvent').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $button = $this.find('button[type="submit"]');
    var eventId = $this.find('input[name="eventId"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/switchStatus',
        data: {
            eventId: eventId
        },
        success:function(data){
             $button.text((!!data.following) ? {% trans "Unfollow"%} : {% trans "Follow"%});
        }
    })
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle to illustrate what I said: https://jsfiddle.net/1u39dhjh/

Note: you should check how to correctly send a form through Ajax with Django, because you don't send the csrf token here.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Your solution is nicer than mine. Where does `data.status` come from? I think the code returned by the view should be: `{'status': 'following'}` or (better?) the JS: `data.following` (boolean) instead of `data.status == 'following'`.

Comment: My bad, I wrote "data.status" instead of "data.following" in the JS. I fixed it. You can use a boolean too, it's up to you.

Comment: Yes, you are returning a boolean in your Django view (it is commented, but nevertheless: `return {"following": !isFollowing}`). You should align the code. Either do not return a boolean but 'following' or check for a boolean in the JS code.